# DBSCAN clustering ValueError

Tags: python, windows, dbscan

I am facing 'Valueerror' and from the error name its not memoryerror.
I have a sparse data which came from a doc2vec model and i am inserting that into DBSCAN model and below is the code i am using

```
myModel = DBSCAN(eps=0.3,min_samples=100, algorithm='brute')
myModel.fit(doc2vec_output_vector)
```

When i execute this code, i am getting below error always.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9a3b7f63ff7c> in <module>()
----> 1 a.fit(textVect)

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\dbscan_.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    282         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    283         clust = dbscan(X, sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 284                        **self.get_params())
    285         self.core_sample_indices_, self.labels_ = clust
    286         if len(self.core_sample_indices_):

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\dbscan_.pyc in dbscan(X, eps, min_samples, metric, metric_params, algorithm, leaf_size, p, sample_weight, n_jobs)
    143         # This has worst case O(n^2) memory complexity
    144         neighborhoods = neighbors_model.radius_neighbors(X, eps,
--> 145                                                          return_distance=False)
    146 
    147     if sample_weight is None:

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.pyc in radius_neighbors(self, X, radius, return_distance)
    588             if self.effective_metric_ == 'euclidean':
    589                 dist = pairwise_distances(X, self._fit_X, 'euclidean',
--> 590                                           n_jobs=self.n_jobs, squared=True)
    591                 radius *= radius
    592             else:

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.pyc in pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1245         func = partial(distance.cdist, metric=metric, **kwds)
   1246 
-> 1247     return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1248 
   1249 

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.pyc in _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1088     if n_jobs == 1:
   1089         # Special case to avoid picklability checks in delayed
-> 1090         return func(X, Y, **kwds)
   1091 
   1092     # TODO: in some cases, backend='threading' may be appropriate

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.pyc in euclidean_distances(X, Y, Y_norm_squared, squared, X_norm_squared)
    244         YY = row_norms(Y, squared=True)[np.newaxis, :]
    245 
--> 246     distances = safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
    247     distances *= -2
    248     distances += XX

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.pyc in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    138         return ret
    139     else:
--> 140         return np.dot(a, b)
    141 
    142 

ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

My input data for dbscan has 300000*300 dimension. can anyone help me on this?

Comment: sklearn apparently tries to compute pairwise distances, in a 300000x300000 array. So you run out of memory, you need a different implementation than "brute".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scikit-learn DBSCAN memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381577/scikit-learn-dbscan-memory-usage)