# DBSCAN: clustering large set of strings in Python

Tags: string, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I'm trying to cluster a column containing 40.000 rows of string data into x number of clusters based on string similarity. I found [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) the appropriate algorithm, as I do not know the intended number of clusters, or words to compare. [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is most suitable as a distance metric for clustering based on string similarity. Code below.

I get a memory error when running the algorithm: my RAM blows up. Scalability seems to be the problem with the dbscan. Running the dbscan on 10 strings is already problematic for my laptop, running on 7+/8 GB RAM for this calculation. Some suggest the Ball_Tree index as solution; in the code below you can see I tried, but same memory problem.

I've seen similar problems in different [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381577/scikit-learn-dbscan-memory-usage). I can find a variation to dbscan, which is the [NG-DBSCAN](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol10/p157-lulli.pdf) and the [dbscan-multiplex](https://github.com/GGiecold/DBSCAN_multiplex), but I can't find a way to implement these methods. Another proposed solution is to use ELKI in Java, but I hope to come to a solution using Python.

I need help with finding a workaround for the memory issue so I can run the dbscan algorithm and cluster the 40k strings in my data file.

This is the code I wrote:

```
df4 = df1[['Omschrijving2']].copy()
data = df4.values

def lev_metric(x, y):
    i, j = int(x[0]), int(y[0])     # extract indices
    return pylev.levenshtein(data[i], data[j])

X = np.arange(len(data)).reshape(-1, 1)

dbscan(X, eps=2, min_samples=50, metric=lev_metric, metric_params=None, 
algorithm="auto", leaf_size=100, sample_weight=None, n_jobs=1)
```

## or BallTree dbscan:

```
eps=2
tree = BallTree(X, leaf_size=30, metric=lev_metric)
tree.query_radius(X, r=eps)
```

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan
 there is a note about "Memory consumption for large sample sizes" and suggestion to use Birch http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#birch

Comment: @AlexBender BIRCH can't use Levenshtein.

Comment: Try with a subset first. Because I don't it will work. Levenshtein is too crude, and short words will connect everything into one big cluster. All Levenshtein distance 2: Trump - trim - tree - the - then - her - sheer. This will likely all merge.

Comment: That is also likely why sklearn's DBSCAN blows up to O(n²) memory.