# Scikit Learn implementation of DBSCAN for 0.7 million data points with 2 columns (Lat and Long) consumes 128GB+ RAM. How to fix this memory issue?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scikit-learn, large-data, dbscan

We are facing memory issues while implementing scikit learn's DBSCAN for 0.7 million data points with 2 columns (latitude and longitude).

We also tried changing epsilon values to small numbers and reducing the number of minimum required points for cluster.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, time
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from geopy.distance import great_circle
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
%matplotlib inline

kms_per_radian = 6371.0088

df = pd.read_csv('data/xxxxxxxxx.csv', encoding='utf-8')

// represent points consistently as (lat, lon).

coords = df.as_matrix(columns=['lat', 'lon'])

// define epsilon as 1.5 kilometers, converted to radians for use by haversine.

epsilon = 1.5 / kms_per_radian



db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=1, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(coords))
```

Kernel killed automatically. Please suggest ways to optimize the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scikit-learn DBSCAN memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381577/scikit-learn-dbscan-memory-usage)

Comment: find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381577/scikit-learn-dbscan-memory-usage

Answer (score 0):

DBScan pre-computes the full O(n^2) distance matrix. Possible solution is to play around and decrease your eps value.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29971331)