# How to cluster large amounts of data with minimal memory usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I am using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata` function to cluster a list of vectors (vectors with 384 components).

It works nice, but when I try to cluster large amounts of data I run out of memory and the program crashes.

How can I perform the same task without running out of memory?

My machine has 32GB RAM, Windows 10 x64, python 3.6 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to choose a different algorithm.

Hierarchical clustering needs O(n²) memory and the textbook algorithm O(n³) time. This *cannot* scale well to large data.

Comment: What would you suggest? I just want an algorithm that creates clusters from a list of vectors. I don't want to specify the number of clusters to be formed

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at

- DBSCAN (or other density-based algorithms) and perhaps this associated discussion: [scikit-learn DBSCAN memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381577/scikit-learn-dbscan-memory-usage)
- [SLINK](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283343/what-is-the-time-and-space-complexity-of-single-linkage-hierarchical-clustering), a variation of hierarchical clustering (set `linkage='single'` in `sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering`)
- [MiniBatch K Means](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html)
- or [BIRCH](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.Birch.html).

However, you will have to set up some pipeline to test different numbers of clusters. It's hard to say which algorithm will work best for you, though.