# Scikit-learn's DBSCAN is giving me me memory errors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

When I cluster on 200.000 x 4 everything seems to be fine and I get good results, but as soon as I reach out to 500.000 x 4 it flops. The entire table is 9.800.000 x 4 so I'm not even close yet.
Looked online for solutions but haven't been able to find any.
I'm not a coder by any means so the lines that are written are not difficult (nor are they written by myself) but not sure where else to go for an answer to my question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\David\Documents\Kutscriptie\hardcoreg2.csv')
data.fillna('0', inplace=True)

data = data.head(500000)

data_cluster = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)

db = DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=6).fit(data_cluster)
```

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b09830897f6a> in <module>
----> 1 db = DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=6).fit(data_cluster)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_dbscan.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    333         # This has worst case O(n^2) memory complexity
    334         neighborhoods = neighbors_model.radius_neighbors(X,
--> 335                                                          return_distance=False)
    336 
    337         if sample_weight is None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_base.py in radius_neighbors(self, X, radius, return_distance, sort_results)
    973                               sort_results=sort_results)
    974 
--> 975                 for s in gen_even_slices(X.shape[0], n_jobs)
    976             )
    977             if return_distance:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1002             # remaining jobs.
   1003             self._iterating = False
-> 1004             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1005                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1006 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    833                 return False
    834             else:
--> 835                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    836                 return True
    837 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    752         with self._lock:
    753             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 754             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    755             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    756             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    207     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    208         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 209         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    210         if callback:
    211             callback(result)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    588         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    589         # arguments in memory
--> 590         self.results = batch()
    591 
    592     def get(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_base.py in _tree_query_radius_parallel_helper(tree, *args, **kwargs)
    786     cloudpickle under PyPy.
    787     """
--> 788     return tree.query_radius(*args, **kwargs)
    789 
    790 

sklearn\neighbors\_binary_tree.pxi in sklearn.neighbors._kd_tree.BinaryTree.query_radius()

sklearn\neighbors\_binary_tree.pxi in sklearn.neighbors._kd_tree.BinaryTree.query_radius()

MemoryError:
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Even if you are not a coder, providing related code and what kind of error is essential to answer your question.

Comment: DBSCAN is indeed memory intensive. You can use HDBSCAN which is usually as good if not better, and needs far less resources. https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Hi, this is already reported here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381577/scikit-learn-dbscan-memory-usage. Read through and let one know if it helps or answers your question. Best

Comment: Hi and thanks. I've added the code and the error I get back. 
I'll have a look at HDBSCAN to see if that is something that would work better. 
In regards to the question being postd earlier, that particular question is 7 years old and their solution is to switch to Java, sklearn also commented that that particular problem should no longer occur.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the memory taken by your dataframe? Look at using smaller datatypes like float32s or categoricals

Comment: I have not tried that, but I'm also not sure how to. Any source that I can read that explains what you mean?

Comment: Hi, I tried similar example on google colab and it worked. So maybe it might be some system bottleneck . HDBSCAN too also take some time. You might need a completely different approach to reduce the memory consumption. Best